# Can I claim a tax credit for child born in October for that calendar year?

Tags: united-states, income-tax

Our new child was born recently (in October) and I am wondering how the tax situation going to be while filing my 2021 taxes in 2022. I am the only one working and my wife doesn't work. Am I eligible to claim any tax credit that has been given by IRS earlier or mid of this year or should I wait until early next year at the time of filing my 2021 taxes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't file taxes and claim any credits for 2021 until 2021 is over and you have *all* of the information necessary to file. Usually this means waiting until mid-January to early February once you get all of your W-2s and other tax forms.

You could *reduce your witholdings* for the rest of the year if you expect to have a lower 2021 tax bill than your witholdings are currently based on, but there's nothing that you can do to get the credit directly until you file your 2021 taxes.

Comment: Thank you. When you say `You could reduce your withholdings for the rest of the year`, you meant to say that I could update my W-4 to reflect a dependent?

Comment: Yes - you get a full year of deduction and credit so you could roughly reduce your withholdings by (deduction+credit)/(# of paychecks). That assumes that your prior withholdings were not taking a child into account.

Comment: @D Stanley - Thanks. And if I decide not to reduce my withholdings for this year, there is nothing going to be anything wrong with W-4, right? I was thinking not to disturb anything for the rest of the year since only 3 months are left for this year to end and maybe make these changes only next year at the time of filing 2021 tax.

Comment: You'll want to change it for next year anyway. You'll likely just get a large tax refund when you file next year.

Comment: Usually you can't preclaim credits, but for the Child Tax Credit in 2021 ONLY IRS is 'advancing' half the estimated/projected credit as six equal payments in July through Dec. See https://www.irs.gov/credits-deductions/advance-child-tax-credit-payments-in-2021 and (many!) pages linked there. It's now after the cutoff for Oct. 15 so if you sign up on the 'update portal' (if you can pass their id-verification process) you should get Nov. and Dec. payments, FWTW.

Comment: (Also if you expect to qualify for the Premium Tax Credit because you buy **health insurance** on the government exchange aka marketplace and _don't_ have other 'minimum essential' and 'affordable' coverage, and your household income (AGI plus some adjustments) will be under 400%FPL, you can have part or all of that credit advanced during the year _to the insurance company_ to partially pay your premiums. You don't receive the money directly, but the premium you actually pay is reduced.)